# List of specific attribute's value in xml using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Rules>
        <Rule id="001">
            <Rule1> name="name1" ruleAttrib="rule1Attribute"</Rule1>
            <Rule2> name="name2" </Rule2>
        </Rule>

        <Rule id="002">
            <Rule3>name="name3"</Rule3>
            <Rule4>name="name4"</Rule4>
            <Rule5>name="name5" ruleAttrib="rule2Attribute"</Rule5>
        </Rule>

        <Rule id="003">
            <Rule6>name="name6"</Rule6>
            <Rule7>name="name7" ruleAttrib=""</Rule7>
        </Rule>

        <Rule id="004">
            <Rule8>name="name8"</Rule8>
            <Rule9>name="name9" </Rule9>
        </Rule>

        <Rule id="005" />

        <Rule id="006">
            <Rule10>name="name10"</Rule10>
            <Rule11>name="name11" ruleAttrib="rule4Attribute"</Rule11>
            <Rule12>name="name12"</Rule12>
        </Rule>
    </Rules>
```

Can't able to print the  attribute value list of specific attribute for e.g ("ruleAttrib")

expected output list:-

1. rule1Attribute
2. rule2Attribute
3. [Empty Space]
4. rule4Attribute

above Index 3 is empty because the rule having id = 003 contains ruleAttrib which doesn't contains anything.

tried code :-

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
List<XElement> ruleGroupList = xdoc.Descendants("Rule").ToList();

foreach (var item in ruleGroupList)
        {
            if (item.Descendants().Attributes("ruleAttrib").exist)
            {
                List<XAttribute> ruleAttriblist = item.Descendants().Attributes("ruleAttrib").ToList();
                Console.WriteLine(ruleAttriblist );
            } 
        }  
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: and what you are getting?

Comment: cant able to apply conditional logic ...that tried code in the if statement is just a conditional statement not a applicable syntax, can't find the replacement of "exist"

Comment: Is your xml correct? I see not closed tag `<Rule12>` and `ruleAttrib` is not xml attribute, it is just a text in a node.

Comment: The values are not attributes.  They are in the innertext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        foreach (var item in ruleGroupList)
        {

            if (item.Descendants().Attributes("ruleAttrib").Count() != 0)
            {
                List<XAttribute> ruleAttriblist  = item.Descendants().Attributes("ruleAttrib").ToList();
                
                foreach (var attrib in ruleAttriblist)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(attrib.Value);
                }
            }

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

> Works Fine... as per the expected output.

Comment: can not find the ruleAttrib in main node so remove the if condition and place in nested inner loop

Comment: Does this compile ?? both loops use the same variable item

Comment: yes ..it compiles ... both are in a different scopes

Comment: That's interesting. Could you please explain how both are in different scope?

Answer (score 0):

Try following which uses xml linq and regex :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            var results = doc.Descendants()
                .Where(x => (x.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (x.Elements().Count() == 0))
                .Select(x => GetAttributes((string)x))
                .Where(x => x != null)
                .Select(x => new { name = x.Groups["name"].Value, rule = x.Groups["rule"].Value })
                .ToList();
        }
        static Match GetAttributes(string innertext)
        {
            string pattern = "name=\"(?'name'[^\"]+)\"\\s+ruleAttrib=\"(?'rule'[^\"]*)";
            Match match = Regex.Match(innertext, pattern);
            if (!match.Success) match = null;

            return match;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ruleAttribute is not an attribute, but it in fact the value(inner text) of the element.

You could use `Linq` to Parse the `Element` (Rulexx) and then use `Regex` to parse the Value associated with `ruleAttrib`.

```
List<XElement> ruleGroupList = xdoc.Root.Descendants("Rule").ToList();
var regex = new Regex("ruleAttrib='(?<value>\\S*)'");
var result = ruleGroupList.Elements()
                          .Select(x=>x.Value)
                          .Where(x=> regex.IsMatch(x))
                          .Select(x=>regex.Match(x).Groups["value"].Value);
```

Output

[image]

If you want to use the format "1.rule1Attribute" then you could use

```
var result = ruleGroupList.Elements()
                          .Select(x=>x.Value)
                          .Where(x=> regex.IsMatch(x))
                          .Select((x,index)=>$"{index+1}.{regex.Match(x).Groups["value"].Value}");
```